# Modifying MVC form collection parameters throwing NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, http-post

We have a third party control that is posting the same form parameters twice. We would like to patch the problem for now and notify them so we can continue using their controls. How do you modify a form parameter that is posted to an MVC controller's action method?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var httpParams = this.HttpContext.Request.Params;
    if (httpParams["form_element"] != null ) {
        httpParams["form_element"] = "some new value"; // NotSupportedException: Collection is read-only
    }
    return new CustomActionResult(this);
}
```

Trying to alter the request parameters does not work - it throws a `NotSupportedException`. Is there a way to redirect this request or do we need some custom HTTPHandler/Module to support this change? We want to control the request body values before the response is processed.

Comment: I don't think you can. But even if you could, what do you intend to do with the request.Params collection after you've updated it? You may want to consider using a specific model parameter and a custom model binder so you can control how it is created.

Comment: Ben - I tried using a custom model binder to modify the FormCollection parameter, but this doesn't help since the proprietary CustomActionResult isn't making use of models - it is only using Request.Form so it wouldn't help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, but I gave up on the issue - as it appears there is no possible way to achieve it. I decided to just fix the issue by removing the duplicate form elements before submitting the form using jQuery on the client.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify `Request.Params` and you should not also. As @Ben mentioned, it will be better if you use parameter or custom ModelBinder if you need to complex binding.

```
public ActionResult Index(string form_element)
{
    if (form_element != null ) {
        form_element = "some new value"; // not sure, why u need this. :)
    }

    return new CustomActionResult(this);
}
```

Or if you have some reason for not doing so, you can just write a wrapper class for the Params, put the logic inside that class. So, it will be easy to modify after the third party control is fixed.

```
public class ParamsWrapper
{
   private NameValueCollection _collection = new NameValueCollection();

   private static ParamsWrapper _instance;

   public static ParamsWrapper Instance {
       if(_instance == null) {
          _instance = new ParamsWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params);
       }

       return _instance;
   }

   public ParamsWrapper(NameValueCollection collection) {
      // added un-duplicated items to _collection from collection;
   }

   // put other methods that you want to interact
   // for example, 
   public string this[string name] {
      get {
          return _collection[name];
      }
   }
}
```

In your action methods or other place,

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var httpParams = ParamsWrapper.Instance;
    return new CustomActionResult(this);
}
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: I cannot use a parameter or model binder - the CustomActionResult will only use Request.Form. It sounds like I would need something higher up in the IIS pipelining.